# How to unhash passwords using john the ripper

Tags: password-hash

i tried unhashing some simple password but john is not producing the unhashed password
I have tried like 3 simple passwords but i haven't been succesful
At first when i started using john the ripper, it used to give unhashed outputs but now it does not

I tried "john --format=lm --wordlist=mywordlist --fork=8 john.txt"

This is what i get
Using default input encoding: UTF-8
Using default target encoding: CP850
Loaded 2 password hashes with no different salts (LM [DES 256/256 AVX2])
Node numbers 1-8 of 8 (fork)
Press 'q' or Ctrl-C to abort, almost any other key for status
4 0g 0:00:00:01 DONE (2024-03-19 17:33) 0g/s 1098Kp/s 1098Kc/s 2196KC/s  LOSER9..�XCVBNM
6 0g 0:00:00:01 DONE (2024-03-19 17:33) 0g/s 1091Kp/s 1091Kc/s 2182KC/s !)(!&&!.ABYGUR
2 0g 0:00:00:01 DONE (2024-03-19 17:33) 0g/s 1091Kp/s 1091Kc/s 2182KC/s !!!M!A!..
7 0g 0:00:00:01 DONE (2024-03-19 17:33) 0g/s 1120Kp/s 1120Kc/s 2241KC/s !!2116!.A6_123
3 0g 0:00:00:01 DONE (2024-03-19 17:33) 0g/s 1049Kp/s 1049Kc/s 2099KC/s !1ABSOL..
8 0g 0:00:00:01 DONE (2024-03-19 17:33) 0g/s 1105Kp/s 1105Kc/s 2211KC/s !!ILOVE..*7¡VA
5 0g 0:00:00:01 DONE (2024-03-19 17:33) 0g/s 1076Kp/s 1076Kc/s 2153KC/s !!N0T.@.IE168
1 0g 0:00:00:01 DONE (2024-03-19 17:33) 0g/s 1030Kp/s 1030Kc/s 2060KC/s !))$DIV..
Waiting for 7 children to terminate
Session completed.

Comment: You don't unhash passwords, you hash words and attempt to find a matching hash.